# Converting the comma seperated string in oracle to the format for the in clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to achieve '2611','2616','3306' from '2611,2616,3306'

```
select REPLACE( '2611,2616,3306', ',', ''',''' ) from dual;
```

The above is giving me the output of 2611','2616','3306.
Can anybody tell how to get the first and the last comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just concatenate them to the front and the back:

```
select '''' || REPLACE( '2611,2616,3306', ',', ''',''' ) || '''' from dual;
```

which would result to '2611','2616','3306'.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in a simple query, although you can using dynamic SQL.  You *could* use the following to search for values in the list:

```
where ','||col||',' like '%,'||YOURLISTHERE||'%,'
```

The addition of the extra commas is so `10` does not match `100`.

Unfortunately, this version of the query cannot take advantage of indexes, so it will often be significantly slower than the `in` version.